# What is a Single<Int>! and how can I instantiate a variable as it

Tags: java, kotlin, reactive, reactivex

I'm trying to solve some test issues and I'm getting the error:

> The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Single!

I've never worked with Single<> and I haven't been able to found how to instantiate a variable as one in Kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found that the *Single* is a class from *Reactivex* and the way to create a variable as *Single* is:

```
Single.just(1)
```

And you can replace the "1" with what you want as the variable.